# Serial port (com port) reading data

Tags: c#, vb.net, binary, serial-port

I have a valentine 1 radar and also the V1Connect (bluetooth adaptor) for it hooked to my PC via a Virtual Serial Port (COM 16).

I am trying to read the data coming from it but all i am getting is gibberish.

My VB.net code is this:

```
Private pendingMsg As New stringbuilder

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each s In System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        lstPorts.Items.Add(s)
    Next s
End Sub

Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    Dim b As Integer

    SerialPort1.ReadTimeout = 50

    Try
        Do While SerialPort1.BytesToRead > 0
            b = SerialPort1.ReadByte
            Me.BeginInvoke(New mydel(AddressOf txt_out), b)
        Loop
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub txt_out(ByVal i As Integer)
    txtReceived.AppendText("&H" & i.ToString("X2") & " ")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SerialPort1.BaudRate = 57600
    SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
    SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
    SerialPort1.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
    SerialPort1.PortName = "COM16" 'lstPorts.SelectedItem.ToString
    SerialPort1.Open()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    SerialPort1.Close()
    txtReceived.Text = ""
End Sub
```

and the output is this:

> &H7F &H0F &HAA &HD8 &HEA &H31 &H09 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H0A &H00 &H00 &HB0 &HAB &H1A &H7F &H7F &H0F &HAA &HD8 &HEA &H31 &H09 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H0A &H00 &H00 &HB0 &HAB &H1A &H7F &H7F &H0F &HAA &HD8 &HEA &H31 &H09 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H0A &H00 &H00 &HB0 &HAB &H1A &H7F &H7F &H0F &HAA &HD8 &HEA &H31 &H09 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H0A &H00 &H00 &HB0 &HAB &H1A &H7F &H7F &H0F &HAA &HD8 &HEA &H31 &H09 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H0A &H00 &H00 &HB0 &HAB &H1A &H7F &H7F &H0F &HAA &HD8 &HEA &H31 &H09 &H73 &H73 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H0A &H00 &H00 &H96 &HAB &HE6 &H7F &H7F &H0F &HAA &HD8 &HEA &H31 &H09 &H73 &H73 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H0A &H00 &H00 &H96 &HAB &HE6 &H7F &H7F &H0F &HAA &HD8 &HEA &H31 &H09 &H73 &H73 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H0A &H00 &H00 &H96 &HAB &HE6 &H7F &H7F &H0F &HAA &HD8 &HEA &H31 &H09 &H73 &H73 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H0A &H00 &H00 &H96 &HAB &HE6 &H7F &H7F &H0F &HAA &HD8 &HEA &H31 &H09 &H73 &H73 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H0A &H00 &H00 &H96 &HAB &HE6 &H7F &H7F &H0F &HAA &HD8 &HEA &H31 &H09 &H73 &H73 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H0A &H00 &H00 &H96 &HAB &HE6 &H7F &H7F &H0F &HAA &HD8 &HEA &H31 &H09 &H73 &H73 &H00 &H00 &H00 &H0A &H00 &H00 &H96 &HAB &HE6 &H7F &H7F &H0F &HAA &HD8

The datasheets for the V1 are:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The full PDF for the ESP can be found [here](http://www.valentine1.com/eula/eula.asp?d=esptech&dl=1)

**I see the &HAA(start) and the &HD8(end) but how do i separate each of those start and ends without keep adding to it?**

Comment: The specification seem to say the data is in binary format and you are trying to read it as text?

Comment: @Peter Please point me in the right direction if you can :o)

Comment: You should not try to read the data as text characters, but rather directly as binary numeric data. I'm not familiar with the Serial Port API, but probably you need to use "read" methods of an stream. If you are unclear about the difference between text and binary data, read this: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/asciiBin.html

Comment: You would have to collect the data belonging to one packet as a unit and then do whatever processing you need. I assume your goal is not to to show raw binary data in a text box. At least now you have data matching your specification.